# Uploading artifacts to nexus with maven from bamboo

Tags: maven, nexus

I have a `maven project` and generated a `war` file from it.  I want to publish this artifact to the `Nexus Oss`. I have edited the `pom` file as well as `/root/.m2/settings.xml` file but still artifacts are not uploading and throwing the following error

```
"Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project CustomerOnBoard: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact CustomerOnBoard:CustomerOnBoard:war:1.1.43-20170221.110417-1 from/to nexus (http://ceala04987.emea.zurich.corp:8081/repository/cob1/): Broken pipe"
```

The repository which is in `Nexus` is `cob`.  We do have configured the proxy in settings file.

Comment: Some more information about the changes you made to `pom` and `settings.xml` may help.  You may also have to add some of the server details so that others can confirm the changes you made are correct.

Comment: Is the bamboo server/agent running as root?  If not, you would need to put the settings.xml file in the `bamboo` user's home directory.